# xCode crash when i run app on my iPhone

Tags: xcode

Hi guys I have a strange problem.

Trying to run my app on the iPhone, xcode has a sudden crash. This only happens if I use my university account to develop. If I sign the application with my personal account (the one where the signature expires after 7 days) xcode does not crash.

Why ?!

If I start the app on the emulator with my university account, do not crash.

:O

This is crash log:

```
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
MainQueue: -[IDEProvisioningManager setDelegate:callbackQueue:]_block_invoke
ProductBuildVersion: 8E3004b
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-12175.1/IDEFoundation/Provisioning/Mechanic/UserActions/IDEProvisioningUserAction.m:125
Details:  method -[IDEProvisioningUserAction userActionName] is a responsibility of subclasses of IDEProvisioningPermissionsFailureUserAction
Object:   <IDEProvisioningPermissionsFailureUserAction: 0x7f9f7d82a870>
Method:   -userActionName
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f9f78e00ce0>{number = 1, name = main}
```

Comment: It's obviously a permissions issue `IDEProvisioningPermissionsFailureUserAction`...

Comment: how to fix....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a permissions issue, and usually happens because the device UDID needs to be added to the developer account you are using.

Once the UDID is added to the account Xcode should be able to create the provisioning profiles and shouldn't crash. If you're not the administrator of the developer account you're trying to use with the device you'll need to ask them to add the UDID of the Apple device to it's certificate.